# Filesystem remounted at login?

Tags: filesystem, xubuntu

If I open a terminal after booting Xubuntu 11.10 and run the command dmesg I see this message at the bottom:

```
EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro,commit=0
```

Do I need to worry about this message? I do not understand why the filesystem needs to be remounted. The partition sda1 contain the whole system.

If I uninstall the display manager this message disappear. If I change the display manager to GDM the message is show again, so it makes no difference what display manager is installed.

Answer (score 1):

Have you been powering off rather than doing a clean shutdown?  I've read some say that this message happens after a file system check is run at boot. The system has to mount read-only during the check and will remount read-write afterward.